# Oracle Apex - Nested check box in radio group

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.2

Is it possible to have a nested check box in a radio group  if one of the options is clicked? I have item P1_Radio_Group and item P1_check_box and would like to nest P1_check_box into P1_Radio_Group dynamically i.e.:

```
(radio button) Option 1
    (check box) Option 1.1
(radio button) Option 2
(radio button) Option 3
(radio button) Option 4
```

I've tried using jQuery insertBefore in a dynamic action:

```
$( "#P1_Radio_Group_1" ).insertBefore( $( "#P1_check_box_CONTAINER" ) );
```

But this changes the check box into a radio button. Is they a way to prevent this?

Comment: Apex offers a number of standard components that suit the vast majority of the requirements. For a specific requirement like this one, you can write an item plugin

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't know.

But you **can** create a radio group (with 4 options) and a checkbox (option 1.1) which will be displayed only if radio button 1 is being selected. You'd do that with a **Show/Hide** dynamic action that also uses client-side condition (i.e. radio button group should have value "1", or whichever value you set it to).

Comment: That is what I'm currently doing, but I want it to be nested under option 1

Comment: Sorry, I can't help with that. Good luck!